# django-filter DateTimeFilter support input with timezone?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have set up a model "Customer" with timezone field and while I use django-filter DateTimeFilter, the input is always in UTC timezone (as per setting).  How can the input can be modified by reference to timezone field in "Customer" model as if I can do it in template which convert the UTC into specific timezone as per the timezone field stipulated in the model. Below is the extracts of the codes:

in models.py

```
import pytz
TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones))

class Customer(models.Model):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES, default='Asia/Hong_Kong')
```

in filters.py

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_edd_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name="edd_date", lookup_expr='gte', label="EDD date >=")
    end_edd_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name="edd_date", lookup_expr='lte', label="EDD date <=")
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

In views.py

```
def userPage(request, slug):
    orders = request.user.customer.order_set.all().order_by('-date_created') 
    myFilter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs
context = {
    'orders': orders,
    'customer': customer,
    'myFilter': myFilter,
}
```

The problem is when I select one of the customer and change the timezone to, say, Pacific/Honolulu. In the user page, it can display properly based on the timezone I set in html,

```
                <td>{{order.edd_date|timezone:customer.timezone|date:"F j, Y a"}}</td>
```

which show one of the record with edd_date is, June 29, 2020 p.m., when I try to filter it with EDD date >= 6/30/2020, the record still exists.  It implies that the input of the filter must be in UTC timezone as the record is actually falling into 6/30/2020 in UTC timezone.

The problem:
How can we set in filters.py to enable the timezone field in "Customer" model can be applied for date/time inputted?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I resolved the problem myself:

In filters.py

```
admin_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')

class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_edd_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name="edd_date", method='tz_gte', label="EDD date >=")
    end_edd_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name="edd_date", method='tz_lte', label="EDD date <=")

    def tz_gte(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        if self.user.is_staff:
            local_tz = admin_tz
        else:
            local_tz = pytz.timezone(self.user.customer.timezone)
        local_dt = local_tz.localize(value.replace(tzinfo=None))
        return queryset.filter(edd_date__gte=local_dt)

    def tz_lte(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        if self.user.is_staff:
            local_tz = admin_tz
        else:
            local_tz = pytz.timezone(self.user.customer.timezone)
        local_dt = local_tz.localize(value.replace(tzinfo=None))
        return queryset.filter(edd_date__lte=local_dt)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['price', 'quantity', 'customer', 'date_created', 'last_updated', 'edd_date', 'cost', 'delivery_date']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(OrderFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In views.py

Changed to:

```
myFilter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders, user=request.user)
```

Now no matter I logged in as admin or different customers with different timezone setting, I can use the filter with timezone matching with different setting, instead of UTC.